# Unit Test With QT

Tags: qt, unit-testing

I have some QT project and I need to write Unit Test first. But I don't know What I have to do.
I have a project "TEST" and another project "UNIT TEST", in project test I write class function include some method,
I want run project UNIT TEST to test all of function in function class but I can't find any right way to do it.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Please read through [this guide](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Include the bits of code and information people need, so they can more easily help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [QtTest module](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qttest.html), which contains classes for unit testing. Very helpful for you may be [tutorial](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtestlib-tutorial.html) and [manual](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtestlib-manual.html) available in Qt Project site. Good way isn't creating separate project for testing, but using project configuration options.